add button interaction logic to an existing Discord message
I have already sent a message to Discord that has a button. How can I add interaction logic to this button without sending a new message? It's similar to how a bot retrieves the role of an emoji, where the bot uses the message ID to perform the logic. I tried to find at least something about it on the Internet but I didn't find anything.
I tried to find something on the internet and ask the ai but its code doesn't work

does the button have a custom ID assigned to it?

no, not assigned. is it necessary?..

yes, it's necessary

how to assign custom ID to the button?

you can't do it if your message is already sent, the only way is to re-send the message with custom ID's already assigned to them. Take a look at the persistent view example

ok i got it thanks for your help
